# How to open Bootstrap modal by using a PHP GET request?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I search but I didn't find any solution for this. I need to create a modal like this.

When we pass **true** in **GET** request the modal must be shown. Otherwise if not any value for $GET request page will be load normally.

I am trying to do this by:

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET["model"=="true"])){
          echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#addstudent').modal('show');
            });
            </script>" ;
         } ?>
```

But it didn't work with my code.

Full code:

```
<?php 
    include_once('../func/islogin.php') ;
  if($login=='false'){
      header('location:../index.php');
  }elseif($login!='true'){
    header('location:../index.php');
  }

  include('../include/conn.php') ;

  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <title>SMS - Sending System</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e491dc23d1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
   <body>
        <?php if(isset($_GET["model"=="true"])){
          echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#addstudent').modal('show');
            });
            </script>" ;
         } ?>
     <section id="container" class="">
       <header class="header dark-bg">
         <div class="toggle-nav">
           <div class="icon-reorder tooltips" data-original-title="Toggle Navigation" data-placement="bottom"><i class="icon_menu"></i></div>
          </div>
          <a href="index.php" class="logo">SFT <span class="lite">හසිත පෙරේරා</span></a>
        </div>
      </header>  <!--header menu end-->
       <?php include('../include/design/slidebar.php') ?> <!--sidebar Include-->
      </div>
     </aside>

    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> Classes</h3>
          </div>
             <?php include('../include/design/statusbar.php') ?>
        </div>

         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-8">
             <section class="panel">
              <header class="panel-heading text-center">
                List Of All Classes
              </header>
            <table class="table table-striped  table-advance table-hover">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th><i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></i></i> Class_ID</th>
                    <th><i class="fas fa-building"></i> Class_Name</th>
                    <th><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></i> Status</th>
                    <th><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Manage</th>
                    <th><i class="icon_cogs"></i> Action</th>
                </tr>
                        <?php 
                        $alldonators="SELECT * FROM classes ";
                        $alldonators_query = mysqli_query($conn,$alldonators);
                        if($alldonators_query){
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($alldonators_query)){ ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Class'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <span
                          <?php if($row['isActive'] == 1){
                               echo " class='text-success'> <i class='icon_check_alt2'></i> Active ";
                              } else{
                                echo " class='text-danger' ><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i> Inactive";
                              }?>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><div class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Manage Class</div></td>
                    <td><div class="btn-group">
                       <?php if($row['isActive'] == 1){
                               echo "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='#'><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i> </a>";
                              } else{
                                 echo "<a class='btn btn-success' href='#'><i class='icon_check_alt2'></i> </a>";
                              }?>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>     
                    <?php  } } ?>
                </tbody>
               </table>
              </section>
             </div>


          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addstudent">
              <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Create New Class
            </button>
             <div class="modal fade" id="addstudent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addstudents" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="addstudent">Add Student-Class</h5>
                   </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form action="../func/saveclass.php" method="POST">
                            <!--  Input Name -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="ClassNameInput" required>Name For Class</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" id="ClassNameInput" name="newclassInput" placeholder ="2020 A/L Matugame" rows="3" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <!--  input current Status -->
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="InputCurrentStatus">Current Status</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="InputCurrentStatus" name="statusInput">
                                      <option value="1">Active</option>
                                      <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                                    </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        <!-- modal-footer -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="saveClassBtn">Save changes</button>
                         </form>
                      </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </section>
               </section>
              </section>




  <!-- container section end -->
  <!-- javascripts -->
  <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- nice scroll -->
  <script src="../js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--custome script for all page-->
  <script src="../js/scripts.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `isset()` statement is wrongly enclosed, you should have:

```php
if (isset($_GET['model']) && $_GET['model'] === 'true')) {
    // TODO
}
```

In short, your assertion needs to be separate to your check to make sure `$_GET['model']` is set.

Comment: Can you paste your complete code since this change, please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you could make a hidden input field and check for the GET parameters and then give it a value. Then in your jQuery check for the value of that input field and show the modal accordingly.

### HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="show_modal" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['model']) && $_GET['model'] === true ? 1 : 0; ?>
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let show_modal = $('#show_modal').val();
    if(show_modal == 1){
        $('#addstudent').modal('show');
    }
});
```